# How to copy the grafana dashboard json to ec2 instance?

Tags: go, amazon-ec2, dashboard, influxdb, grafana

In my use case I am using influxdb and grafana for monitoring. When I launch the new instance I want the dashbboard to setup programmatically. I mean copying the exported json to some location.

I am not sure where to copy the dashboard json file after installing grafana.

Or do I need to make an api call with the json. I am using golang in the backend. So I can do that through an API call.

I am fairly new to grafana. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it through the API. The documentation for the dashboard can be found [here](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/). To get started you will probably need to create an API token, see [here](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/http_api/) for more details.

In your case, you just need to import a json file. Here is an example with curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <your API Token>" -X POST --data '{
  "dashboard": {
    "id": null,
    "title": "Production Overview",
    "tags": [ "templated" ],
    "timezone": "browser",
    "rows": [
      {
      }
    ],
    "schemaVersion": 6,
    "version": 0
  },
  "overwrite": false
}' http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db
```